# swift Variable of struct not useable in switch statement

Tags: struct, switch-statement, swift4.2

I want to switch between 2 image-sources.
I have the following struct:

```
struct AppConstants {

static var imageSource:String = "goral"

static var fixURL = URL(string: "https://picsum.photos/375/375/?random")

struct Domains {

    static let baseurl = "http://www.m.myapp2go.de/services/"

}...
```

In the following code in my viewController and i can not access the var "AppConstants.fixURL" in the switch statement:

```
 switch AppConstants.imageSource { // is filled with a value of a picker
    case "goral":
         let randomInt = Int.random(in: 1...12)
         let AppConstants.fixURL = URL(string: "http://www.m.myapp2go.de/pics/\(randomInt)_goral_item.jpg")

    case "picsum":
         let randomInt = Int.random(in: 1...1080)
         let AppConstants.fixURL = URL(string: "https://picsum.photos/375/375/?\(randomInt)")

    default:
        print("other")
    }
```

With the error-message:

> Reference to member 'fixURL' cannot be resolved without a contextual type
>   and
>   Type annotation missing in pattern

Comment: remove the let in the front of  let AppConstants.fixURL = URL(string: "http://www.m.myapp2go.de/pics/\(randomInt)_goral_item.jpg").  You define new constat, but you would like to assigned the value to existing var.

Comment: @user3441734 THX, this is working now !